# Why UILabelViewRepresentable does not respect to given frame?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a simple UILabelViewRepresentable and I gave a frame to it! But after using in SwiftUI it became max size! How could I solve the issue from UIKit code part?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        UILabelViewRepresentable(configuration: { label in
            
            label.text = "Hello, World!"
            label.textAlignment = .center
            label.backgroundColor = .blue
            label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50)

        })
 
    }
    
}




struct UILabelViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    let configuration: (UILabel) -> ()
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UILabel {
       return UILabel()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UILabel, context: Context) {
        configuration(uiView)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that this representable will try constrain the `UILabel` to fill the whole screen. You can avoid this by making a `UIView`, and making the `UILabel` a child of that so you can center it in the parent.

Code:

```
struct UILabelViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    let configuration: (UILabel) -> ()

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        view.addSubview(UILabel())
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        let label = uiView.subviews.first! as! UILabel

        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiView.centerXAnchor),
            label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiView.centerYAnchor)
        ])

        configuration(label)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        UILabelViewRepresentable(configuration: { label in
            label.text = "Hello, World!"
            label.textAlignment = .center
            label.backgroundColor = .blue
            label.sizeToFit()
        })
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Depending on your usage, the `label.sizeToFit()` can be moved inside the `UILabelViewRepresentable`.

Comment: Thanks, That is working! Why force unwrapping? Should not we use if let?

Comment: @swiftPunk I guess I made an assumption that nobody would mess with the label's `superview`, but maybe could be worth checking. However, if someone has messed with the superview and broken the functionality, then maybe it is worth crashing so the developer knows their code is incorrect. Up to you really

Comment: I tried your answer, it solves the issue of Label, but SwiftUI thinks the UILabelViewRepresentable is max size! How can I sole this new issue? Look: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUecs.png

Answer (score 0):

```
struct ContentView: View {

var body: some View {
    
    UILabelViewRepresentable(text: "Hello, World!",
                             center: .center,
                             frame: CGRect(x: 0,
                                           y: 0,
                                           width: 200,
                                           height: 50),
                             background: .blue)
        }
    }
struct UILabelViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {

    let text : String
    let center: NSTextAlignment
    let frame: CGRect
    let background: UIColor
    

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
    let view = UIView()
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = text
    label.textAlignment = center
    label.backgroundColor = background
    label.frame = frame
    view.addSubview(label)
   return view
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your code cannot solve my question issue. I am returning a UILabel not UIView.